# syscall() to call tkill()

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals, system-calls

**Hello**

is it safe to send *signal* to each thread of the process using *tkill()* linux kernel call? 
as it is not directly exposed, i call it using *syscall().*

i am refering to the link - <http://linux.die.net/man/2/tkill>.

but i dont know whether i should do certain **check prior** to the call (like state check or lock mutex etc..)?

Thanks
Sandeep

Comment: What do you want to achieve which the POSIX library doesn't do?

Comment: i want to send Signal SIGUSR1 to each thread of a process periodically. and handle it. there are kill() and sigqueue(), but those does not guaranty that signals would be handled by respective thread each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the pthread library  pthread_kill(). This is what it is for.

Comment: tkill() and pthread_kill() works with 2 different thread ID's do you know what is relation between then? and how to retrive one from the other?

Comment: when a native thread is finished, its Thread id can be reused by other thread.. so is it the same as for thread ID used by pthread library..

Comment: @sandeep pthread_kill uses the pthread library thread ID. tkill uses the kernel task id (which in kernel sources is called "process id"). The relation between the two is totally undefined and is implementation specific.